# Iniciante em angular Problemas com observable

Tags: angular

Sou novo no mundo de desenvolvimento em angular e estou com um problema simples mais não consigo resolver.

Iniciei o projeto utilizando angular cli 1.5.2, onde esta utilizando angular 5.0.0

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta simples a api com caminho em http://localhost:3333/app/users/login, utilizando o postman consigo acesso a ela.

Coloquei o observable no construtor da pagina, mais o codigo simplesmente é ignorado, não faz a requisição nem chega a mostrar ela no network do navegador.

Segue os unicos arquivos que alterei ao iniciar a aplicação com angular cli para sass.

Podem me ajudar a realizar esse request ?

arquivo appComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    http.post('http://localhost:3333/app/users/login', { email: 'teste', password: 21323 })
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log('veio')
    });



  }

}
```

arquivo app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Opa esqueci de dizer mais não tem nenhum erro de compilação do type script ou webpack

Answer (score 0):

Olá depois de pesquisar mais ainda, e conversar com alguns amigos, acabei descobrindo que a requisição não estava sendo respondida correta, ao trocar map por subscribe a requisição começou a funcionar.